# Have SSH on port 80 or 443 while webserver (nginx) is running on these ports

Tags: debian, ssh, port-forwarding, nginx

I have a remote Linux (Debian) machine which I'd like to access from a very restricted network. In fact the only two open ports are port 80 (for HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).

On this machine I have nginx server which is running on port 80 and 443.

I haven't done anything like this before and am fairly inexperienced with any server software other than nginx (and Minecraft which isn't particularly hard to do).

If there is a simple way to achieve this please tell me.

The ssh server on this machine is this: `OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`

Comment: You could run SSH on port 80, nginx on some other port and then use port-forwarding whenever you need HTTP access to nginx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml). It can multiplex the connections depending on what type of client is asking. So if a webbrowser comes along it will forward it to nginx and if a ssh client tries to connect forward it to the sshd. The [README.md](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/blob/master/README.md#configuration) will hook you up with a nice explanation on how it has to be configured.

Answer (score 3):

```
restricted_net=1.2.3.0/24
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s "$restricted_net" -p tcp --dport 80 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
```

**undo**

```
iptables -t nat -L -nv --line-numbers
```

shows the number of the added rule. If it is the first rule in this chain then it can be deleted with

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1
```

It can be deleted direcly, too:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -s "$restricted_net" -p tcp --dport 80 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
```

Comment: Ok. I will try this tomorrow. Since I don't know the IP address nor am I inside it right now.

Comment: Just a little note: It would be nice if you also posted the command to undo this

Comment: Has anyone successfully gotten this to work? I'm wanting to get SSH working over HTTPS for SSH Authentication with Git.