# How to use ssh over http or https?

Tags: sshd, http-proxy

I have a linux fedora21 client laptop behind a corporate firewall (which lets through http and https ports but not ssh 22) and I have a linux fedora21 server at home behind my own router.
Browsing with https works when I specify my home server's public IP address (because I configured my home router)

Is it possible to ssh (remote shell) to my home server over the http/s port?

I saw a tool called `corkscrew`. would that help?

`opensshd` and `httpd` run on the home server. What else would need configuration?

Comment: put your sshd at home to listen on port 443, but you should disable port 443 on your home httpd.

Comment: I can't quite though that. I need httpd(s) for git pushed as well. so I gotta have a httpd listening on 443.

Comment: try httptunnel - yum install httptunnel [http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html](http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html), or as you mentioned in your question: corkscrew.

Comment: Either way, sshd would listen to 22, and httpd to 80/443 and httptunnel or corkscrew would forward traffic httpd receives to sshd ?

Comment: Yes. It don't have to change ports of your services.

Comment: Does the firewall allow SSH traffic on port 443? Many do, but some don't. If yours allows it, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9551/i-am-failing-to-clone-a-git-repo-when-behind-a-proxy/9589#9589

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/108097/19753 may include a bit more details for some cases than the answers here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19161960/32453

Comment: Note: Ensure that you are legally allowed to tunnel through your company / educational institution's firewall before doing so!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What is possible depends on what the firewall allows.

#### If the firewall allows arbitrary traffic on port 443

Some firewalls take the simple way out and allow anything on port 443. If that's the case, the easiest way to reach your home server is to make it listen to SSH connections on port 443. If your machine is directly connected to the Internet, simply add `Port 443` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/sshd_config` just below the line that says `Port 22`. If your machine is behind a router/firewall that redirects incoming connections, make it redirect incoming connections to port 443 to your server's port 22 with something like

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i wan0 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:22
```

where `wan0` is the WAN interface on your router and 10.1.2.3 is your server's IP address on your home network.

If you want to allow your home server to listen both to HTTPS connections and SSH connections on port 443, it's possible — SSH and HTTPS traffic can easily be distinguished (in SSH, the server talks first, whereas in HTTP and HTTPS, the client talks first). See http://blog.stalkr.net/2012/02/sshhttps-multiplexing-with-sshttp.html and http://wrouesnel.github.io/articles/Setting%20up%20sshttp/ for tutorials on how to set this up with [sshttp](https://github.com/stealth/sshttp), and also [Have SSH on port 80 or 443 while webserver (nginx) is running on these ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173805/have-ssh-on-port-80-or-443-while-webserver-nginx-is-running-on-these-ports)

#### If you have a web proxy that allows CONNECT tunnelling

Some firewalls block all outgoing connections, but allow browsing the web via a proxy that allows the [HTTP `CONNECT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling) method to effectively pierce a hole in the firewall. The `CONNECT` method may be restricted to certain ports, so you may need to combine this with listening on port 443 as above.

To make SSH go via the proxy, you can use a tool like [corkscrew](http://freecode.com/projects/corkscrew). In your `~/.ssh/config`, add a `ProxyCommand` line like the one below, if your web proxy is `http://web-proxy.work.example.com:3128`:

```
Host home
HostName mmm.dyndns.example.net
ProxyCommand corkscrew web-proxy.work.example.com 3128 %h %p
```

then you can connect by just running `ssh home`.

#### Wrapping SSH in HTTP(S)

Some firewalls don't allow SSH traffic, even on port 443. To cope with these, you need to disguise or tunnel SSH into something that the firewall lets through. See http://dag.wiee.rs/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/ for a tutorial on doing this with [proxytunnel](https://proxytunnel.sourceforge.io/).

Comment: the 443 trick did it! I was surprised this works :) - any sysadmin sight why this seems to be the case with most firewalls?

Comment: @AK_ Because although it's possible for a firewall to distinguish TLS from SSH, it's an additional configuration step and costs more in performance, for no real benefit when it comes to outgoing connections (since anything could be tunnelled in TLS anyway).

Comment: @Gilles, Are there even proxy servers that block HTTPS yet allow HTTP CONNECT HTTPS?

Comment: @Pacerier Many of them. It's not that the proxy blocks HTTPS — a proxy doesn't block connections that bypass the proxy — it's that direct connections are blocked, but the proxy allows CONNECT with any traffic provided that it's to port 443. There's no real way to filter HTTPS anyway, short of root of trust injection and certificate rewriting which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Note you can also use netcat-openbsd instead of corkscrew in the proxy comand: `ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x  __proxy_IP__:__port__  %h %p`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [sslh](https://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh/README.html) if you want to run BOTH an HTTPS server and an SSHd server on the same port 443.

Answer (score 3):

you can try another way, set up a web server, which can ssh your server,

https://github.com/huashengdun/webssh