# How do I ssh into a server over HTTPs?

Tags: ssh, nginx, proxy, http, squid

I have a server that has a reverse proxy (NGINX) set up to host all my other websites/services on a single server. I would like to create a way to SSH into that server over HTTP. The reason I need to do it this way is that my server is running behind a VPN with port forwarding so the outside internet only has access to my server through a single IP and a single port.

I'm a little confused if this is possible or what I should be doing. From what I've seen I heard that I should set up a HTTP proxy on that server. Do I use SQUID for this?

Looking for some guidance please.

Comment: I would ask this in https://serverfault.com/

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190490/how-to-use-ssh-over-http-or-https

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/355271/ssh-over-https-with-proxytunnel-and-nginx

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to expose your SSH port to the internet (and thus having two ports opened) you will have to connect to your server through VPN and then start SSH connection on server's private IP, or server's LAN IP depending on your environment. HTTPS and SSH are different secure protocols and are not compatible, some sort of VPN will be needed if you do not want to expose SSH port. You may also check port-knocking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking